# Execute local binary from local webform?

Tags: html, user-interface, interface

Does anyone know of a Linux or platform independent equivalent to Windows' "hypertext application". My understanding is that this technology allows you to execute local binaries from a web browser. For example, apparently the following will open Excel. I haven't tested since I'm not running Windows.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Run Executable HTA</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<body bgcolor=#565656>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var prog = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office\\Excel.exe";
oShell.run ('"'+prog+'"',1);
window.close();
</script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Optimally I would like to be able to specify arguments in a form and trigger a run from my web-browser. Returning output is not necessary and everything runs a on the local machine so security is not a priority either.

The simpler the solution the better since my motivation for going in this direction is to get a cheap and dirty GUI up and running quickly so I can concentrate on more interesting aspects of the project...

Comment: Hmm. There's [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) that offers HTA like functionality, but it doesn't seem to feature any security relaxations. Not sure whether anything like this exists - you may be best off relying on shell scripts running locally

Comment: Yeah I've read some pretty negative things about Prism so I'll take your advice and find some GUI tools for bash scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You also could take a look at the integration between Qt and WebKit.

This might be an overkill for your purpose, but it makes it very easy to export the APIs (C++, for instance POSIX function system()), into the JavaScript environment that runs inside such a web browser.

It is the easiest way to create domain-specific web browsers.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. The key thing being able to access system() and pass a few arguments. I'm also looking at Zenity and easybashgui..